# Why are pictures not displayed in django?

Tags: python, django

[image]

Why are the pictures that are loaded through the admin panel in Django not displayed?
this is code of views.py

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
template_name = 'Homepage/index.html'
model = Goods
context_object_name = 'goods'

def get_queryset(self):
    """
    Return the last five published questions (not including those set to be
    published in the future).
    """
    return Goods.objects.filter(
        pub_date__lte=timezone.now()
    ).order_by('-pub_date')[:1]

def description(self):
    return self.description_text

def price(self):
    return self.price_text

def image(self):
    return self.image_sale
```

this is code of models.py

```
class Goods(models.Model):
description_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
price_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
image_sale = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='media/')
pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published', null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.image_sale
```

this is code of settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

And this construction

[image]

this is code of app urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'Homepage'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/results/', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

this is coode of index.html

```
{% if good.image %}
    <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ good.image_sale }}">
    {% endif %}
```

[image]

Comment: What's your related HTML code?

Comment: @Christophe ok i added the html code

Comment: Try this : `"{% static 'your_path/your_image.ext' %}"` (you need only one filed and use the complete path (subfolder to your media folder) + file name + extension)

Comment: Is this in your development environment (did you set up the dev-server to serve media?) or production?

Comment: @thebjorn Does it matter?

Comment: Yes.  Look at serving media files in development at https://djangocentral.com/managing-media-files-in-django/

Comment: try `good.image_sale.url` instead of `good.image_sale`

Comment: @ashdaily Tried it, doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was entering photos incorrectly in the html
This is code models.py

```
class Goods(models.Model):
description_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
price_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
image_sale = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='images/')
pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published', null=True)



def __str__(self):
    return self.description_text

def __str__(self):
    return self.price_text
```

this is code of views.py

```
class HomeView(ListView):
model = Goods
template_name = 'index.html'

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
template_name = 'Homepage/index.html'
model = Goods
context_object_name = 'goods'

def get_queryset(self):
    """
    Return the last five published questions (not including those set to be
    published in the future).
    """
    good = Goods.objects.filter(
        pub_date__lte=timezone.now()
    ).order_by('-pub_date')[:1]
    return good

def description(self):
    return self.description_text

def price(self):
    return self.price_text
```

this is code of app urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from . import views

app_name = 'Homepage'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/results/', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
    path('', views.HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),

]
```

this is code of urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),  # grappelli URLS
    path('', include('Homepage.urls')),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

this is html code

```
{% for good in goods %}
<img src="{{good.image_sale.url }}">
{% endfor %}
```

And this is the construction of the site
[image]

Special thanks to @em0ji. This is a guy from the Russian Stack Overflow community who solved my problem for this, many thanks to him.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do in your template

```
{% if good.image_sale %}
    <img src="{{good.image_sale.url }}">
    {% endif %}
```

please you can modify queryset first to check if the image is presented

```
    def get_queryset(self):
    
    """
    Return the last five published questions (not including those set to be
    published in the future).
    """
    good = Goods.objects.filter(
        pub_date__lte=timezone.now()
    ).order_by('-pub_date')[:1]
    return good
```

Comment: I added this part but it doesn't work

Comment: can you make an HTML inspection after rendering to check the rendered HTML????

Comment: Are you sure there is a problem in views.py ?

Comment: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'image'

Comment: no maybe the object of the database itself doesn't have an image so I added some code to just show  the image url if it found

Comment: so you got the problem so if you need the first object make the remove` [:1] ` and add `.first` from query set

Comment: Like this? `good = Goods.objects.filter(
            pub_date__lte=timezone.now()
        ).order_by('-pub_date').First`

Comment: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'First'

Comment: sorry first() not First()

Comment: 'Goods' object has no attribute 'image'

Comment: replace image with image_sale this may  i will  change on answer

Comment: Yes I replaced but now I have a different error 'Goods' object is not iterable'

Comment: can you post whole template code

Comment: I am currently working on fixing the problem

Comment: also can you show me what print out in shell

Comment: please apply last edit code if you have for loop in templates

Comment: Sorry for disappointment, but the picture is still not displayed.

Comment: if you available we can letme know

Comment: yes i solved the problem, you can see what changes were made to the project in my answer